# can't insert numbers with multiple dots into nvarchar field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a c# SqlCommand to insert a version number into the revVersion field of nvarchar(50). This is no problem for values like 1.13 or 1.6, but for value 1.18.1.12 i get a

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '.1'.'

This is the faulty command:

`"INSERT INTO Revision (revVersion,year,month,day,numLinesAdded,numLinesRemoved,moduleName) VALUES (1.18.1.12,2015,10,29,7,5,'bp-bn-bmfilter-600.m1,v')"`

Thank you for your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing single quotes `' '` (`1.18.1.12`) & `','` (`'bp-bn-bmfilter-600.m1,v'`) :

```
INSERT INTO Revision (revVersion, year, month, day, numLinesAdded, numLinesRemoved, moduleName) 
     VALUES ('1.18.1.12', 2015, 10, 29, 7, 5, 'bp-bn-bmfilter-600.m1', 'v');
```

Comment: the 'bp-bn-bmfilter-600.m1,v' was intentional as the v belongs to the filename but you are right with the quotes on the first one. Cheers!

Comment: Using SqlCommand parameters instead of hardcoded constants you can avoid this kind of errors and to prevent the code of SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use quote '1.18.1.12' as it's datatype is nvarchar

```
INSERT INTO Revision (revVersion,year,month,day,numLinesAdded,numLinesRemoved,moduleName) 
     VALUES ('1.18.1.12',2015,10,29,7,5,'bp-bn-bmfilter-600.m1','v');
```

Answer (score 0):

1.13 or 1.6 both are number but 1.18.1.12 this is not number thats why you got error

You have to change it string format like below

```
INSERT INTO Revision (revVersion,year,month,day,numLinesAdded,numLinesRemoved,moduleName) 
     VALUES ('1.18.1.12',2015,10,29,7,5,'bp-bn-bmfilter-600.m1','v');
```

Answer (score 0):

missing single quote:

```
INSERT INTO Revision (revVersion,year,month,day,numLinesAdded,numLinesRemoved,moduleName) VALUES ('1.18.1.12',2015,10,29,7,5,'bp-bn-bmfilter-600.m1,v')
```